# Truncate text with Range API

Tags: javascript, html, css, truncate

I have a div with text, which I wanna truncate, after one remains only text which can fit. Code below. In internet I only found a plugins, that depends on JQuery, but I know, it possible to do with [Range](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range), if someone had experience, please show me, how do this.

```css
.container {
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```js
const container = document.querySelector('.container');
let lines = container.querySelectorAll('.text');

const bottomLine = container.getBoundingClientRect().bottom;
for (let line of lines) {
  if (line.getBoundingClientRect().bottom > bottomLine) {
    container.removeChild(line);
  }
}
```

```css
.container {
  height: 60px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> Take a look

```css
.container {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  overflow: auto;       /* Try using hidden, scroll, auto or overlay */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
  <div class="text">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</div>
</div>
```

> Explanation: You can either make the container

1. Scrollable: By using overflow: auto;
2. Non Scrollable: Just plain hides the rest of the content by using overflow: hidden